# Handlebars set variable and tofixed

Tags: templates, handlebars.js, helper

I have an issue with Handlebars' templates. I need to implement the `toFixed(2)` function in a template. For that, I've registered the following helper functions:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('amountFixed', function(amount) {
   return amount.toFixed(2);
});
Handlebars.registerHelper('var',function(name, value, context){
   this[name] = value;
});
```

So, when I user var and amountFixed functions, with hardcoded numbers, it works. But when I change it to dynamic value, it throws an error

Hardcoded value: this works

```
{{var "amount" 2342.2363}}
<li class="list-subtotal">
   <div>Subtotal</div>
   <div></div>
   <div class="text-right">{{../this.subtotals.1.quantity}}</div>
   <div class="text-right">${{amountFixed amount}}</div>
</li>
```

Dynamic value: Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'toFixed' of undefined.

```
{{var "amount" ../this.subtotals.1.amount}}
<li class="list-subtotal">
   <div>Subtotal</div>
   <div></div>
   <div class="text-right">{{../this.subtotals.1.quantity}}</div>
   <div class="text-right">${{amountFixed amount}}</div>
</li>
```

Does anyone know, how to fix this?

Comment: Mostly, you are referring an undefined value in  `../this.subtotals.1.amount`. Can you please provide your JSON data here?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks :)